# How to return to main viewcontroller from bottom uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

If I have a tableview that has say 3 levels that the user can drill down, when the user selects the last cell are you able to send them back to the main view controller not just the level above the one you are on now?

```
first table
--- second table
-------third table ---->cell selection takes you back to the first table to populate fields?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a navigation controller to "drill down" and that your table is in the root view controller, how about UINavigationController's [`popToRootViewControllerAnimated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated%3a) method?

Comment: yep thanks, that should work.. I have a main view that i use to navigate to different uitableviews.. so when using that function it should just pop back to the last tableview on the stack.. thanks.